# After adding a row in a CRUD in grid telerik, updating or deleting button are not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, telerik, crud

I have a CRUD with stored procedures and I need to work it with kendo grid. The controllers and the buttons of adding, editing and deleting are working perfectly, but after I add a row in my CRUD, these buttons (except the add) are not working. I mean, after I add, all the buttons start to just add, even if I push the button of edit or delete and I don't know what's wrong.

My controller:

```
        private Entities db = new Entities();

        ClientDB cliDB = new ClientDB();

        // GET: Client
        public ActionResult ClientIndex()
        {
            return View("ClientIndex");
        }

        public ActionResult ClientRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(cliDB.ListAll().ToDataSourceResult(request));

        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ClientCreate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, t_Client t_Client)
         {
            return Json(cliDB.Add(t_Client), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ClientUpdate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, t_Client t_Client)
        {
            return Json(cliDB.Update(t_Client), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult ClientDelete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string c_Id)
        {
            Guid g = Guid.Parse(c_Id);
            return Json(cliDB.Delete(g), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The class where i call my stored procedures:

```
public class ClientDB
    {
        private SqlConnection con;

        private void connection()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;
            con = new SqlConnection(cs);

        }

        public List<t_Client> ListAll()
        {
            connection();
            List<t_Client> lst = new List<t_Client>();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_SelectClient", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            lst = (from DataRow rdr in dt.Rows
                   select new t_Client()
                   {
                       c_Id = (Guid)rdr["c_Id"],
                       c_Name = rdr["c_Name"].ToString(),
                       c_NoClients = rdr["c_NoClients"].ToString(),
                       c_DocType = rdr["c_DocType"].ToString(),
                       c_DocNumber = rdr["c_DocNumber"].ToString(),
                       c_TaxpayerType = rdr["c_TaxpayerType"].ToString(),
                       c_DianClassification = rdr["c_DianClassification"].ToString(),
                       c_Address = rdr["c_Address"].ToString(),
                       c_AddrType = rdr["c_AddrType"].ToString(),
                       c_Telephone = rdr["c_Telephone"].ToString(),
                       c_BusinessName = rdr["c_BusinessName"].ToString()
                   }).ToList();

            return lst;
        }


        public int Add(t_Client client)
        {
            connection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertUpdateClient", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Id", client.c_Id);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_NoClients", client.c_NoClients);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Name", client.c_Name);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_DocType", client.c_DocType);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_DocNumber", client.c_DocNumber);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_TaxpayerType", client.c_TaxpayerType);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_DianClassification", client.c_DianClassification);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Address", client.c_Address);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_AddrType", client.c_AddrType);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Telephone", client.c_Telephone);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_BusinessName", client.c_BusinessName);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Insert");
            int i;
            con.Open();
            i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            return i;
        }

        public int Update(t_Client client)
        {
            connection();
            int i;
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertUpdateClient", con);

            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Id", client.c_Id);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_NoClients", client.c_NoClients);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Name", client.c_Name);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_DocType", client.c_DocType);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_DocNumber", client.c_DocNumber);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_TaxpayerType", client.c_TaxpayerType);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_DianClassification", client.c_DianClassification);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Address", client.c_Address);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_AddrType", client.c_AddrType);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Telephone", client.c_Telephone);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_BusinessName", client.c_BusinessName);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "Update");
            con.Open();
            i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return i;
        }

        public int Delete(Guid c_Id)
        {
            connection();
            int i;
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_DeleteClient", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_Id", c_Id);
            con.Open();
            i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return i;
        }

    }
```

The cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CRUD5.Models.t_Client>()
        .Name("grid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px; height:800px:" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_NoClients).Title("Clients").Width("auto");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_Name).Title("Name");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_DocType).Title("Doc Type");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_DocNumber).Title("Doc Number");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_TaxpayerType).Title("Taxpayer Type");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_DianClassification).Title("Dian Classification");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_Address).Title("Address");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_AddrType).Title("AddrType");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_Telephone).Title("Telephone");
            columns.Bound(c => c.c_BusinessName).Title("Business Name");
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Create();
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.c_Id))
            .Read(read => read.Action("ClientRead", "Client"))
            .Create(create => create.Action("ClientCreate", "Client"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("ClientUpdate", "Client"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ClientDelete", "Client"))
        )
)
```

My stored procedures and my table:

```
CREATE TABLE t_Client(
 c_Id   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  PRIMARY KEY    DEFAULT NEWID(),
 c_NoClients NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_Name NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_DocType NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_DocNumber NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_TaxpayerType NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_DianClassification NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_Address NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_AddrType NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_Telephone NVARCHAR(100) NULL, 
 c_BusinessName NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
 c_Action NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
 c_Estate NVARCHAR(6) NULL,
 ValidFrom DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,
 ValidTill DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
 PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTill)
)
WITH
(
    SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON
    (
        HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.t_ClientHistory,
        HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = 10 YEARS
    )
 )
GO

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Insert and Update Client 

Create Procedure SP_InsertUpdateClient    
(    
 @c_Id uniqueidentifier,
 @c_NoClients NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_Name NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_DocType NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_DocNumber NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_TaxpayerType NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_DianClassification NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_Address NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_AddrType NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_Telephone NVARCHAR(100),
 @c_BusinessName NVARCHAR(100),
 @Action varchar(10)    

)    
As    
Begin    
if @Action='Insert'    
Begin    
insert into t_Client(c_NoClients, c_Name, c_DocType, c_DocNumber, c_TaxpayerType, c_DianClassification , c_Address , c_AddrType , c_Telephone , c_BusinessName ) 
        values (@c_NoClients,  @c_Name,  @c_DocType,  @c_DocNumber,  @c_TaxpayerType,  @c_DianClassification ,  @c_Address ,  @c_AddrType ,  @c_Telephone ,  @c_BusinessName   )
End    
if @Action='Update'    
Begin    
update t_Client set 
     c_NoClients = @c_NoClients,
     c_Name = @c_Name,
     c_DocType = @c_DocType,
     c_DocNumber = @c_DocNumber,
     c_TaxpayerType = @c_TaxpayerType,
     c_DianClassification = @c_DianClassification,
     c_Address = @c_Address,
     c_AddrType = @c_AddrType,
     c_Telephone = @c_Telephone,
     c_BusinessName = @c_BusinessName
     where c_Id = @c_Id    ;    
End  
End


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Delete Employee  

Create Procedure SP_DeleteClient  
(    
@c_Id uniqueidentifier
)    
as     
Begin    
if exists (select * from t_Client  where c_Id = @c_Id )
update t_Client  set c_Estate = 'false' where c_Id = @c_Id;
update t_Client set c_Action = 'Delete' where c_Id = @c_Id;
End
```

Comment: Very complete and understandable question, well done! As a starting point, you should return a `DataSourceResult` in all you CRUD operations, see the controller in  this example: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup Do you get any messages in your browser's console?

Comment: @CarstenFranke Thank you so much for responding, but it doesn't work because i'm using for the ClientDB a "public int" and it's necessary for the called to the Stored Procedure, and if i try to add the **DataSourceResult*** it generates an error:                                                                                                                            ""int" doesn't contain a definition for "DataSourceResult" and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult (DataTable, DataSourceRequest)' requires a receive of type 'DataTable'"

Comment: Then wrap it into an array: `return Json(new[] { cliDB.Update(t_Client) }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));` If the `Update` or any other operation returns an `int`, you should consider to retrieve the updated object and return it instead. Otherwise the grid cannot work properly with what you are returning. Check out the examples from Kendo what they send and what they receive to see how they are doing it. Btw. you can remove the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` for non-GET-requests.

Comment: @CarstenFranke if i return it into an array, it still doesn't work and if i try to send it as  an object, the way i did, it didn't work and i don't know what to do. Could you please indicate me how to send it? please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what is the problem, it just needed a function that reload the Grid. The  things that I've changed are in the .cshtml.

Inside the .DataSource I've added the .Events that calls the function "onRequestEnd"

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.c_Id))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("ClientRead", "Client"))
                    .Create(create => create.Action("ClientCreate", "Client"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("ClientUpdate", "Client"))
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ClientDelete", "Client"))
                    .Events(events =>
                    {
                        events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd");
                    })
                    )
```

and this is the function :

```
<script>

    function onRequestEnd(event) {
        console.log(event.type);
        if (event.type == "update" || event.type == "create" || event.type == "destroy") {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();  
        }
    }

</script>
```

Additional to this, I've corrected some things that @CarstenFranke recommended me, so the final controllers are:

```
private Entities db = new Entities();

        ClientDB cliDB = new ClientDB();

        // GET: Client
        public ActionResult ClientIndex()
        {
            return View("ClientIndex");
        }

        public ActionResult ClientRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(cliDB.ListAll().ToDataSourceResult(request));

        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ClientCreate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, t_Client t_Client)
        {
            return Json(new[] { cliDB.Add(t_Client) }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ClientUpdate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, t_Client t_Client)
        {
            return Json(new[] { cliDB.Update(t_Client) }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult ClientDelete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string c_Id)
        {
            Guid g = Guid.Parse(c_Id);
            return Json(new[] { cliDB.Delete(g) }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from what I can understand from your question is that once you add in a new item the system just keeps working in `add` mode with the new item.

From looking at the code you don't ever seem to be resetting/setting the id of the new item you are adding so the grid and datasource will assume that the item you are adding and subsequently returning is a new item based on the `default` id that it is given when it constructs a new item.

All you should need to do is regenerate the id as a new guid and then save that result to the server and then return the newly created object with the new guid as the id so for example:

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult ClientCreate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, t_Client t_Client)
         {
             t_Client.c_Id = Guid.NewGuid();
             cliDB.Add(t_Client); 
            return Json(new[] {t_Client}.DataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much for responding, but the change that you proposed it didn't work, when I add a row, all the controls just add, even when I click "update" or "Delete". The thing is that before I add a row, the controls work perfectly, the problem is after I add a row.

Comment: My Grid is in the question, i'm sorry, i can't comment it here because is too long for adding it. The Grid is where says "The cshtml"

Comment: Yes I saw the grid after I posted my comment. Which is why I deleted it.  So what is being returned back when you inspect the result of the create process?

Comment: When I create the row, i put the debug on it creates normally and put the answer correctly, but, what I said, when I click the update or delete button, it gets into the controller ClientCreate and in ClientDB gets into Add

Comment: I am more interested in what is being returned back to the grid from the http response. So if you look at the browser network response that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good practice to reload the Grid after creating new record. It will solve the problem but will increase the number of times you access the database getting the data because you will reload the grid after every Add process even the failed ones.

Grid Create ActionResult method should return the newly crated object with the new generated ID PrimaryKey. So you should update your `ClientCreate` to be like this:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ClientCreate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, t_Client t_Client)
    {
        return Json(new[] { cliDB.Add(t_Client)}.ToTreeDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

`cliDB.Add(t_Client)` method should return the newly created object not `int`

You can have a look at the documentation and demos from telerik here
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline